# Strange execution time improvement while listening to debug connections

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

Versions(Don't think it's gonna be very helpful but):

PHP: 5.4

Apache: 2.2

XDebug: 2.3.1

PHPStorm: 8.0.1

When I run my PHP Web Application(without debug listenning or PHPStorm working) the execution time (By Firebug) is about 1.5 seconds.
When I Start Listening PHP Debug Connections(by PHPStorm) and run my application - the execution time drops to 150 milliseconds or even to 70 ms

I don't understand what's happening with it. Is PHPStorm caching something?
And what time should I consider to be true?

I don't know what additional information you may need so sorry for that

**Update:**
As Linus Kleen mentioned, the thing is that XDebug fails to open connections to client multiple times which slows the application

Comment: I experienced this just a couple of days ago also. Is `xdebug.remote_enable` set to "On" by any chance? Enable xdebug logging. You'll probably see a lot of failed connection attempts.

Comment: @LinusKleen, Yes, The xdebug.remote_enable=on
And I see In log lots of failed connections when No Listening and Success While Listening.
So this is why the time is increased without debugging?

Comment: I assume yes. Much appreciations, Linus

Comment: That's correct -- if you have have enabled `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` or xdebug cookie/parameter is still passed with request .. then xdebug will try to connect to debug client (PhpStorm in your case) for approx 1 second and only then it will proceed with code execution. If it's connected with no delay .. or does not tries to connect at all, then there will be no such delay.

Comment: @LazyOne, Thanks for confirmation)

Comment: @Eugene, it's [perfectly valid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own question and accept that. That's preferable over editing the question with **Update**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@LinusKleen and @LazyOne mentioned that the reason is xdebug remote connections. To be specific - these directives: xdebug.remote_enable=on, xdebug.remote_autostart=on

XDebug is trying to connect to the client and fails in case of Listening PHP Debug Connections Disabled (Connection atеmpt repeats several times which takes about second of execution time)

When Listening PHP Debug Connections is enabled - XDebug success to connect with 1 attempt and does not waste time.